# How do I ensure all nodes are running at the same time in K8S for jobs with parallelism

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I need to run a job with parallelism, but I need all nodes/pods running at the same time. If I have only 4 nodes available, but I need 5 then they need to all remain pending or the submission needs to fail as a whole. How do I enforce this in the manifest file? Currently what I see is it takes up as many nodes as it can and leaves the rest in pending state.

Here's my manifest:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  parallelism: 93 #expecting the job to stay pending or fail
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 30
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: indatapt
          hostPath:
            path: /data # folder path in node, external to container

      containers:
      - name: myapp-container
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: DEMO_GREETING
          value: "Hello from the environment"
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo "b" >> /indata/b.txt && /indata/test.sh && sleep 10s']
        volumeMounts:
          - name: indatapt
            mountPath: /indata  # path in the container
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: yes, that is correct. You need to find another solution to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: @Jonas does that mean I need to build a service to manage this a layer above or is there a manifest template that I can use?

Comment: yes, a custom service or a custom kubernetes controller and CRD.

Comment: @Mr.UNOwen Does it answer your question?